# Why jump signed instruction is working oppositely

Tags: assembly, x86, masm, flags

I know that `js` instruction is jump if sign flag is set.  I want to make a procedure that compares each element of an array and counts if the difference
of two elements is less than 5.

```
CountMatch proc
    push ebp
    mov ebp, esp
    push esi
    push edi
    mov ecx, [ebp + 12]; length of arrays
    mov esi, [ebp + 20]; address of array1
    mov edi, [ebp + 16]; address of array2

CHKMATCH :
    mov eax, [esi]
    sub eax, [edi]
    jns ELSEloop    ;this line is problem
    neg eax
    cmp eax,5
    ja CONTINUE
    inc count
    jmp CONTINUE
ELSEloop:
    cmp eax,5
    ja CONTINUE
    inc count

CONTINUE :
    add esi, 4
    add edi, 4
    loop CHKMATCH

    mov eax, count
    call writeint
    call crlf
    pop edi
    pop esi
    pop ebp
    ret 16
CountMatch endp
```

When the program is running the `CHKMATCH` loop, it may work correctly because if the difference is negative, the sign flag is set. So it could be negated and compared with 5.  But it doesn't work, so I changed it to `jns`.
In Debug mode I couldn't find the sign flag but I can see PL flag.

Comment: `jns` sounds correct for your description which is slightly vague. Looks like you want to negate the difference if it's negative so you can compare with 5. So yeah, you need a `jns` for that to skip to `ELSEloop`.

Comment: x86 doesn't have a `PL` flag or condition-name (ARM does: it's equivalent to x86's `ns` condition: sign flag not set).  On x86, `SF` is a bit in EFLAGS.

Comment: The sign flag (SF) is set when the result of an instruction is negative. SF is bit 7 (hex 80) of EFLAGS, As commented by Jester, `jns` should work. The code seems to be setup to take 4 parameters, but only 3 of them are used. What is the last parameter pushed onto the stack, which would end up at [ebp+8] ?

Answer (score 1):

The code you posted is correct; and I don't know why you thought you wanted `js` in the first place.

Note that it'd be simpler to do this:

```
    mov eax, [esi]
    sub eax, [edi]      ;eax = difference maybe (if it didn't overflow)
    jns NOT_NEGATIVE    ;If difference is not negative (sign flag not set), don't negate
    neg eax             ;Difference was negative, so negate it to make it positive
NOT_NEGATIVE:
    cmp eax,5
    ja CONTINUE
    inc count
CONTINUE:
```

Also; you said (in the question's description) "counts if the difference of two elements is less than 5" and the code actually does "counts if the difference of two elements is less than or equal to 5". Depending on what you actually want, you might need to use `jae CONTINUE` (or its synonym, `jnb CONTINUE`).

Finally, it's probably faster to keep `count` in a register (e.g. maybe in `edx`); and if you do that it's probably faster to avoid the branch using a trick like:

```
NOT_NEGATIVE:
    cmp eax,5          ;Set carry flag if difference < 5
    adc edx,0          ;Add carry flag to count
CONTINUE:
```

In that case, you can also get rid of the `mov eax,count` by swapping `eax` and `edx` everywhere; like maybe:

```
CountMatch proc
    push ebp
    mov ebp, esp
    push esi
    push edi
    mov ecx, [ebp + 12]   ; length of arrays
    mov esi, [ebp + 20]   ; address of array1
    mov edi, [ebp + 16]   ; address of array2
    xor eax,eax           ; eax = count = 0

CHKMATCH :
    mov edx, [esi]
    sub edx, [edi]      ;edx = difference maybe (if it didn't overflow)
    jns NOT_NEGATIVE    ;If difference is not negative (sign flag not set), don't negate
    neg edx             ;Difference was negative, so negate it to make it positive
NOT_NEGATIVE:
    cmp edx,5          ;Set carry flag if difference < 5
    adc eax,0          ;Add carry flag to count
CONTINUE:
    add esi, 4
    add edi, 4
    loop CHKMATCH

    ; eax = count already

    call writeint
    call crlf
    pop edi
    pop esi
    pop ebp
    ret 16
CountMatch endp
```

Comment: Ouch; if you care about speed on Intel CPUs (not just recent AMD) then you need to replace the slow `loop` instruction as well, with `dec ecx/jnz`

Comment: @PeterCordes: I was also tempted to transform it into "single induction variable form" (e.g. `mov edx,[esi+ecx*4]` and `sub edx, [edi + ecx*4]` with the removal of the `add esi,4` and `add edi,4`), but was getting a little worried OP would be overwhelmed (too much at once).

Comment: Yup, that would be a win except on Sandybridge/Ivybridge, where an indexed load can't stay micro-fused in the OoO back-end.  Haswell and later can for `sub`, though, because it's a 2-operand instruction with a RMW register destination.  You can instead index one array relative to the other, e.g. `sub esi,edi` before the loop, then `mov edx, [esi+edi]` / `sub edx, [edi]` so only the pure load is indexed.  (Increment with `add edi,4`)